# App is crashing due to mlmodel file url not found in iOS 13 beta and above

Tags: crash, ios13, coreml

Have been using ml model in my app.It was working awesome below iOS 13.But the same mlmodle get crashed in iOS 13 and above.Please guide me asap.I feel its a bug with Apple .PFB logs

> [coreml] MLModelAsset: load failed with error Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Invalid URL for .mlmodel."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid URL for .mlmodel.}
>
> 2019-09-14 18:32:58.776078+0530 Testing[565:205914] [coreml]
>   MLModelAsset: modelWithError: load failed with error Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Invalid URL for .mlmodel."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid URL for .mlmodel.}
>
> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Invalid URL for .mlmodel."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid URL for .mlmodel.}:
>
> 2019-09-14 18:32:58.777056+0530 OrigoTesting[565:205914] Fatal error:
>   'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Invalid URL for .mlmodel."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid URL for .mlmodel.}: file
>   ModelWrapper.swift, line 30

In My Model Wrapper file i have below code

```
public init(url: URL) {

    print("url :\(url)")

    self.model = try! TestModel(contentsOf: url)

}
```

This code works below iOS 13 very well.

Please guide.

Comment: What is the URL? Is it to a .mlmodel or .mlmodelc?

Comment: URL is a path where .mlmodelc is present.                                                
       Eg : let myBundle = Bundle(for: TestModel.self)

            let machineModelURL = URL(string: myBundle.path(forResource: "TestModel", ofType: "mlmodelc") ?? "")

Comment: did you solve the problem? @SVS

Comment: Not yet.Still the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The model will get compiled, when you bundle your app. For iOS 13 you have to search for `.mlmodelc` in your bundle, the `.mlmodel` file doesn't exist on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: modelDestination)
```

instead of

```
URL(string: modelDestination)
```

when creating the compiled url.